# Combinatorics -- committee of 4 problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

The problem at hand is that we want to select a committee of 4 people from a pool of 6 men and 7 women (this problem is from a textbook, I didn't come up with it). We want to know how many ways we can select a committee with at least one woman. Here's my (incorrect, but I'm not sure why) attempt:

Ways to select a committee with one woman: $(7)_{women}((6)(5)(4))_{men}=840$

Ways to select a committee with two women: $((7)(6))_{women}((6)(5))_{men}=1260$

Ways to select a committee with three women: $((7)(6)(5))_{women}((6))_{men}=1260$

Ways to select a committee with four women: $((7)(6)(5)(4))_{women}=840$

Now I combine all of these to get 4200. However, the answer is supposedly 700, because we simply compute how many total ways we can select a committee (715) and subtract the number of ways we can select just men (15) and get 700. This makes sense, but I don't understand why my approach is wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $(6)(5)(4)$ men has to be divided by $6$ permutations, since the order of the men doesn't matter. Similarly for the other calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @GerryMyerson ! What I don't quite get is: why does my approach necessitate order? I don't specify in which order the men must be selected...

Comment: You chose any of the $6$, then any of the other $5$, then any of the other $4$. For example, you chose Andrew first. Then Bob. And then Carl. This is one way to do it. But you could choose Carl first, then Andrew, then Bob. It is exactly the same $3$ men. But you count it as the other way to form a men’s part of the committee. In fact, every triple of men is counted $3!=6$ times, that’s the number of ways to choose these $3$ men in different orders.

Comment: @Aig Ohhhhh, I see. Thank you!